# How to sync changes between various markup files generated by Pandoc?

Tags: latex, synchronization, markdown, markup, pandoc

all. I'm using [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) as my writing tools. Its amazing ability to convert between various markup formats (markdown, LaTeX, HTML) impresses me. "One source file, multi output formats" sounds good, but I've got some problems about syncing changes between the markdown formats.

Let's say, I start by writing the markdown source file, name `hello.mkd`. I list my tasks in time sequence:

1. Finish composing the `hello.mkd` file.
2. Use pandoc to convert `hello.mkd` to `hello.tex` and `hello.html`.
3. Edit `hello.tex`: add some packages, add some complicated environment to make the TeX document more beautiful.
4. Refine `hello.html`.

Here comes the problem: If I find a typo, or other bugs when I edit `hello.tex`, shall I fix it in `.tex` immediately or shall I fix it in the source file `hello.mkd` and regenerate the outputs?

Two choices for me:

- Fix the bugs in source file `hello.mkd`, then regerate all the outputs, which refer to `hello.tex` and `hello.html` here. Then I have to merge all changes made towards the specific file types, for example, merging all the packages/environment et al. changes into the newly generated file.
- Fix the bugs in every output formats, that is, fix it in `hello.mkd`, `hello.tex`, `hello.html`, and more fixes/filetypes if you like. Well, this method requires less merge work. But it looks ridiculous because the three share-rooted markup files seem irrelevant now.

Hmm...what do you think?

Answer (score 5):

Try using custom templates (`--template` option) to get the customization you need in HTML and LaTeX.  Also look at the `-H`, `-B`, `-A`, and `--css` options.  These options are designed to allow you to refine the output while still generating it from a single markdown source.